# Div height is adjusting to height of child div when child div is floating left, but not when it's floating right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm working on my sister's website.

I have a problem with the DIV height not adjusting to 100% of the hight of all its child elements. What's weird is that for the child div in question, if I set the float to left, the height adjusts fine, but when it's floating right the containing div comes up short.

Site: http://www.lindsaybryden.com/

Floating Right:
[image]

Floating Left:
[image]

How can I get the height adjusting properly while floating the child div right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing only the left float, not the right float. Try adding

```
<br style="clear: both;" />
```

just before the close of divContainer.

Comment: When you float an element it takes it out of the typical document flow. Elements can then overflow their containers because the container doesn't actually know where they are. The clear style attribute says 'hey, take those floats into account again!' You can clear just left, just right or both.